# What is opposite of falsetto?

Tags: idioms, terminology

When a person makes their voice squeaky it’s called falsetto, often by men to imitate or mimic a woman. When a person deepens it, what’s it called? I’ve heard both men and women do it.: women to imitate or mimic a man, or by a man to sound like a baritone or bass.

Comment: 'falsetto' is not just a high squeaky voice used to imitate women. It's an actual technical singing term.

Comment: About the best that an online thesaurus will give you is "low-pitched".

Comment: Maybe repost this to SEs Music Practice & Theory site?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the opposite of a 'false' vocal register would just be the normal vocal register, or **modal voice**

wiki:

> [Falsetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsetto) is the vocal register occupying the frequency range just above the modal voice register and overlapping with it by approximately one octave.
>
> [Modal voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_voice) is the vocal register used most frequently in speech and singing in most languages. It is also the term used in linguistics for the most common phonation of vowels. The term "modal" refers to the resonant mode of vocal folds; that is, the optimal combination of airflow and glottal tension that yields maximum vibration.

The lowest vocal register is apparently referred to as the **vocal fry register** -- is this what you were looking for?

> The [vocal fry register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_fry_register) (also known as pulse register,
>   laryngealization, pulse phonation, creak, croak, popcorning, glottal
>   fry, glottal rattle, glottal scrape, or strohbass) is the lowest vocal
>   register and is produced through a loose glottal closure that permits
>   air to bubble through slowly with a popping or rattling sound of a
>   very low frequency.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the OP is asking about an octive **below** the modal voice.